# ASP.NET Core MVC : validation open unformatted page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm learning with a small ASP.NET Core MVC application and I'm encountering a problem validating the data entered. I entered data with a modal popup and everything works correctly with the validations included in the model, but when performing other types of validations instead of showing the error in the popup it does by redirecting to the same page but without format and not modal.

This is my code - model class:

```
    [Key]
    public int IDArbitro { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    [Display(Name = "Apellidos")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Los apellidos son obligatorios")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} no debe exceder de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(20)")]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre es obligatorio")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} no debe exceder de {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult InsertOrUpdate(int id)
    {
        Arbitro arbitro = new Arbitro();

        if (id > 0)
        {
            arbitro = _context.Arbitros.Where(x => x.IDArbitro == id).SingleOrDefault();
        }

        return PartialView("InsertOrUpdate", arbitro);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult InsertOrUpdate(Arbitro arbitro)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ValidarDatos(arbitro))
            {
                if (arbitro.IDArbitro == 0)
                {
                    _context.Arbitros.Add(arbitro);
                }
                else
                {
                    _context.Arbitros.Update(arbitro);
                }                    

                _context.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("List", "Arbitro");
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("InsertOrUpdate", arbitro);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("InsertOrUpdate", arbitro);
        }
    }

    private bool ValidarDatos(Arbitro arbitro)
    {
        bool isOK = true;

        if (_context.Arbitros.Any(x => x.Nombre == arbitro.Nombre 
                                  && x.Apellidos == arbitro.Apellidos 
                                  && x.IDArbitro != arbitro.IDArbitro))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Ya existe un arbitro con el nombre {arbitro.Nombre} y los apellidos {arbitro.Apellidos}");

            isOK = false;
        }

        return isOK;
    }
```

View:

```
@model FootballStats.Models.Arbitro
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Modificar";
}

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="insertOrUpdateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="insertOrUpdateModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header bg-dark">
                @if (@Model.IDArbitro == 0)
                {
                    <h3 class="text-white"><strong>Añadir árbitro</strong></h3>
                }
                else
                {
                    <h3 class="text-white"><strong>Modificar árbitro</strong></h3>
                }
            </div>

            <form asp-controller="Arbitro" asp-action="InsertOrUpdate" data-ajax-method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="IDArbitro" />

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control sm" asp-for="Nombre" type="text" />
                        <!--<span asp-validation-for="Nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
                        <p style="color:#FF0000" ;>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Nombre)</p>-->
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label class="form-label">Apellidos</label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control sm" asp-for="Apellidos" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>                                        
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

[This is when validation works well and show error correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vz0Qj.jpg)

[And this is when validation show the same page without styles and popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6Bwv.jpg)

I hope that with this code someone can easily detect the error I am making.

Comment: Could you please tell me which property you mentioned not work well? According to your codes all of the three property is string format and what you mean about redirect to the same page? Do you mean the model pass the validation?

Comment: Hello Brando, thank you. ModelState.IsValid is True, but if it is not, the application correctly displays the corresponding error in the popup form, the problem is when the second validation (ValidarDatos function) does not pass, in that function I call ModelState.AddModelError and that is the error that is displayed without formatting and on a new page.